# apply() is giving NA values for every column

Tags: r, apply

I've been having this strange problem with `apply` lately. Consider the following example:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(cars, foo = sample(LETTERS[1:5], size = nrow(cars), replace = TRUE))
head(df)
  speed dist foo
1     4    2   E
2     4   10   E
3     7    4   B
4     7   22   E
5     8   16   D
6     9   10   C
```

I want to use `apply` to apply a function `fun` (say, `mean`) on each column of that `data.frame`. If the `data.frame` is containing only `numeric` values, I do not have any problem:

```
apply(cars, 2, mean)
speed  dist 
15.40 42.98
```

But when trying with my `data.frame` containing `numeric` and `character` data, it seem to fail:

```
apply(df, 2, mean)
speed  dist   foo 
   NA    NA    NA 
Warning messages:
1: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
2: In mean.default(newX[, i], ..) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA                 
3: In mean.default(newX[, i], ...) :                              
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Of course, I was expecting to get `NA` for the `character` column, but I would like to get values for the `numeric` columns anyway.

```
sapply(df, class)
    speed      dist       foo 
"numeric" "numeric"  "factor"
```

Any pointers would be appreciated as I'm feeling like I'm missing something very obvious here!

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first sentence of the description for `?apply` says:

> If X is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null dim
>   value (such as a data frame), apply attempts to coerce it to an array
>   via as.matrix if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data frame) or via
>   as.array.

Matrices can only be of a single type in R. When the data frame is coerced to a matrix, everything ends up as a character if there is even a single character column.

I guess I owe you an description of an alternative, so here you go. data frames are really just lists, so if you want to apply a function to each column, use `lapply` or `sapply` instead.

Answer (score 5):

`apply` works on a matrix, and a matrix must be of all one type. So `df` is being transformed into a matrix, and since it contains a character, all the columns are becoming character.

```
> apply(df, 2, class)
      speed        dist         foo 
"character" "character" "character"
```

To get what you want, check out the `colwise` and `numcolwise` functions in `plyr`.

```
> numcolwise(mean)(df)
  speed  dist
1  15.4 42.98
```

Answer (score 3):

You are applying a function over the columns of a data.frame. Since a data.frame is a list, you can use `lapply` or `sapply` instead of `apply`:

```
sapply(df, mean)

speed  dist   foo 
15.40 42.98    NA 
Warning message:
In mean.default(X[[3L]], ...) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

And you can remove the warning message by using an anonymous function that tests for class numeric before calculating the mean:

```
sapply(df, function(x)ifelse(is.numeric(x), mean(x), NA))

speed  dist   foo 
15.40 42.98    NA
```

Comment: You could also use `suppressWarnings(sapply(df, mean))` to remove the warning.  However this will suppress any warnings whereas your version will only suppress the warning we know will happen and don't care about so yours is probably a better solution.